# Getting response 404 on non-root routes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

1.When I try to send GET request to "/families" route my application responses me with 404.

Controller:

```
package com.example.controller;

import com.example.domain.*;
import com.example.repository.*;
import com.example.view.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public class FamilyController {
    private FamilyRepository familyRepository;

    public FamilyController(FamilyRepository familyRepo) {
        this.familyRepository = familyRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getFamily(){
        List<Family> families = familyRepository.findAll();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);

        String result = "";
        try {
            result = mapper
                    .writerWithView(FamiliesView.class)
                    .writeValueAsString(families);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
package com.example;

import com.example.controller.*;
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ConstantaServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConstantaServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

2.But when I try to change route to "/" both in Controller annotation and GET request I'm getting

```
"message": "Content type '' not supported"
```

Mapper work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect mapping.

Either set `/families` prefix for whole controller using `@RequestMapping` annotation on controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/families", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public class FamilyController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getFamily(){...}
}
```

or adjust `@GetMapping` annotation on your `getFamily` method

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public class FamilyController {
    @GetMapping("/families")
    public String getFamily(){...}
}
```

or register for whole application context path prefix `/families` by setting config property `server.servlet.context-path` to value `/families`

Answer (score 0):

In your code above you can remove @RequestMapping from the controller level.

```
@RequestMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
```

The controller should look like this.

```
@RestController
public class FamilyController {
```

To learn more about the behavior you can follow some tutorials  like [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller)